# Не понятная конструкция кода

Tags: java, многопоточность, classloader

При проверки кода, столкнулся с данной конструкцией, `ContextClassLoader`, из того что я вижу не был инициализирован, непонятно что вернётся в `cl` переменную метода `ClassLoader getContextClassLoader()`, не должен ли `ClassLoader getContextClassLoader()` вернуть `null`?

```
 ClassLoader getContextClassLoader() {
    return (ClassLoader)
            AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() { 
        public Object run() {
            ClassLoader cl = null;
            try {
                cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(); // Что содержит CL на данный момент ? 
            } catch (SecurityException ex) { }
            return cl;
        }
    });
}
```

Ниже код внутри `Thread` класса:

```
  @CallerSensitive
    public ClassLoader getContextClassLoader() {
        if (contextClassLoader == null)
            return null;
        SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (sm != null) {
            ClassLoader.checkClassLoaderPermission(contextClassLoader,
                                                   Reflection.getCallerClass());
        }
        return contextClassLoader;
    }

 /* The context ClassLoader for this thread */
    private ClassLoader contextClassLoader;

public static native Thread currentThread();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ContextClassLoader`, из того что я вижу не был инициализирован

`ContextClassLoader` инициализируется в методе [`Thread.init(..)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.init%28java.lang.ThreadGroup%2Cjava.lang.Runnable%2Cjava.lang.String%2Clong%29)

> непонятно что вернётся в `cl` переменную метода `ClassLoader getContextClassLoader()`
>
> не должен ли `ClassLoader getContextClassLoader()` вернуть `null`?

В переменную `cl` метод [`Thread.getContextClassLoader()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader()) вернет либо `ClassLoader`, либо `null`.

Comment: Дело в том что так как я зашол в исходники наткнулся на метод init(), но пустой, зашол на исходники через IDEA а не Grep Code.. метод не принимал никаких параметров, поэтому и решил задать вопрос, я присоеденю в дальнейшем код который кидает на init().